# Crosstab SQL query for 2 tables?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables and I need to make one view of them like if it was 1 single table

Table1 DEVICE

```
+-----+-------+-----------+
|DevID|DevName|DevIP      |
+-----+-------+-----------+
|1    |HH1    |192.168.1.1|
+-----+-------+-----------+ 
|2    |HH2    |192.168.1.2|
+-----+-------+-----------+
```

Table2 DEVICECUSTOMDATA

```
+-----+------------+--------+
|DevID|Name        |Value   |
+-----+------------+--------+
|1    |Model       |CN70    |
+-----+------------+--------+
|1    |BuildVersion|1.2     |
+-----+------------+--------+
|1    |BuildDate   |20140113|
+-----+------------+--------+
|2    |Model       |MC55    |
+-----+------------+--------+
|2    |BuildVersion|1.2     |
+-----+------------+--------+
|2    |BuildDate   |20140110|
+-----+------------+--------+
```

The resulting table should be:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+-----+------------+---------+
|DevID|DevName|DevIP      |Model|BuildVersion|BuildDate|
+-----+-------+-----------+-----+------------+---------+
|1    |HH1    |192.168.1.1|CN70 |1.2         |20140113 |
+-----+-------+-----------+-----+------------+---------+
|2    |HH2    |192.168.1.2|MC55 |1.2         |20140110 |
+-----+-------+-----------+-----+------------+---------+
```

I would appreciate any help to do this.   Thanks

Comment: You have to use `PIVOT` to get that result. What DB are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

SQL SERVER:

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e318f/5):

```
SELECT d.DevId, d.DevName, d.DevIp, p.Model, p.BuildVersion, p.BuildDate
FROM DEVICE d
JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM DEVICECUSTOMDATA
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR Name IN ([Model], [BuildVersion], [BuildDate])) as Something) p
on d.DevId = p.DevId
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Online Example (SQL Server Syntax): [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/375)

**Result:**

[image]

**SQL Script:**

```
    DECLARE @Device TABLE (
    DevID int not null,
    DevName varchar(max) not null,
    DevIP varchar(max) not null
)

insert into @Device values ('1', 'HH1','192.168.1.1')
insert into @Device values ('2', 'HH2','192.168.1.2')

DECLARE @DeviceCustomData TABLE (
    CDevID int not null,
    Name varchar(max) not null,
    Value varchar(max) not null
)

insert into @DeviceCustomData
values ('1','Model','CN70')
insert into @DeviceCustomData
values ('1','BuildVersion','1.2')
insert into @DeviceCustomData
values ('1','BuildDate','20140113')

insert into @DeviceCustomData
values ('2','Model','MC55')
insert into @DeviceCustomData
values ('2','BuildVersion','1.2')
insert into @DeviceCustomData
values ('2','BuildDate','20140110')

SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT d.DevID, d.DevName, d.DevIP, c.Value, c.Name
    FROM @Device d 
inner join @DeviceCustomData c on d.DevID = c.CDevID) AS SourceTable
PIVOT(
    MIN(Value)
    FOR Name in ([Model],[BuildVersion],[BuildDate])
) as PivotTable
```

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx